# Where exactly in YOLO's architecture is the input image divided into a grid?

Tags: cnn, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I am currently studying the YOLO algorithm for a project. What I'm not quite sure about is where exactly the input image is divided in an SxS grid. After my research on the paper, videos and websites I am still doubting whether the input image is divided before it is fed to the Convolutional neural network (see the architecture below) or divided inside the CNN. If so, the input is pre-distributed into the grid cells. How does the network take into account the grid cells in the Convolution layers? [image: YOLO architecture]

I did research on the paper and other resources related to YOLO. I want to know when the input image is divided, with that I can understand the structure better.

Comment: In the first convolutional layer.

Comment: Thank you Kern! And is it true that the 7x7x30 output is projected onto the input image for the bounding boxes on the image?